# How to run a program from one of the projects in a solution as a build step?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

The problem is as follows: My VS2015 solution has several projects, among them A and B.

A is a regular project that contains a program/service/code that can translate certain source files into compiled resources (with the idea being that the source is human-maintanable and under source control but the resulting resource is machine-optimized but not under source control).

Project B contains one such source file and instead of being put verbatim in project B's resulting assembly, I want the program in A to "compile" it into a resource file and only put that in assembly B (along with other code in project B that compiles normally).

```
+-------------------+                    +-----------------+
|Project A          |                    |Assembly A       |
|                   | +----------------> |                 |
|                   |                    |                 |
+-------------------+                    +-------+---------+
                                                 |
                                                 |
                +--------------------------------+------+
                |                                       |
+-------------------+                    +-----------------+
|Project B      |   |                    |Assembly B    |  |
|          +----+---+                    |        +-----v--+
|          |src.txt|| +----------------> |        |res.txt||
|          |       ||                    |        |       ||
|          +--------|                    |        +--------|
+-------------------+                    +-----------------+
```

How to do it in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Maybe call the exe of the program you want to run via a .bat file in the desired build step of the other program? I've done other commands in .bat files, so it sounds possible that way..

Comment: @Botonomous Credit for the diagram goes to http://asciiflow.com/. I was looking into MSBuild documentation, but verbose as it is, it didn't give me any ideas yet. Hoping someone here can explain it more to the point.

Comment: If you make sure projectA builds before projectB then there's no reason you shouldn't be able to use A's output in B's build? Your question is very broad though, what kind of aswer are you looking for? I doubt it's just 'yes, it's possible in VS 2015' :P What have you tried?

Comment: @stijn Haven't tried much as I don't even know how to begin. I don't know the syntax of pre-/post-build steps, have even less clue how to run a program from another project in such a step. I suppose a simple example would help where, say, Project A knows how to ROT13 files and Project B has a build step where one of its files is encoded before being put in the assembly.

Comment: It's a bit hard to do this in one solution. How much code is in A? You could define an [inline task in MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx) that runs as a prebuild target which will on the fly compile some code and run it using whatever input items you want (src.txt, etc.). The output would be the list of transformed files, which you could add to the item group "EmbeddedResource" via the [output element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164287.aspx) to have them included as resources.

Comment: @mikez Care to post this as an answer? I'd switch to it as accepted answer as it's the one that I have seemingly nailed down to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic principle is straightforward, and can be implemented as such: make sure A builds before B and then use A.exe as a prebuild step in B.

To get the build order correct: open the .sln with two projects in VS, right-click projectB, select 'Build Depedencies->Project Depedencies...' and make projectB depend on projectA. verify in the build order tab that A will be built before B.

Now open projectB in a text editor, scroll all the way to the end and add something like this right before the `</Project>` end tag:

```
<Target Name="GenerateSomeFile" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SourceFile>$(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)\in.cs</SourceFile>
    <TargetFile>$(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)\out.cs</TargetFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Command="/path/to/projectAOutputDir/A.exe $(SourceFile) $(TargetFile)"
</Target>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this using a Visual Studio Custom Tool, rather than a pre-/post-build step. This isn't really a *compile* step as much as a *designer* transform, but should still solve the question I think you're asking. This creates a custom code generator similar to how Visual Studio converts resource strings from a .resx designer into compilable C# code.

You didn't specify what version of .NET you're targeting, but this assumes you're targeting .NET 4.5. There's a [good tutorial here](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/developing-custom-tool-aka-single-file-generators-for-visual-studio-2012/) for creating your own Custom Tool, which is what the following is based on. Just note that that article was written for Visual Studio 2012, so some of the registry keys are different.

Summary of what all this does:

1. Implement a `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.BaseCodeGenerator` in Project A. This does whatever you're doing to convert from a `src.txt` input file to a `res.txt` output file.
2. Register your generator from step 1 as a VS2015 Custom Tool
3. Set the properties of your `src.txt` in Project B to use your custom tool. From now on, every time you save or modify `src.txt`, Visual Studio will generate your `res.txt` for you, which you can embed into your Assembly B or whatever you like. Just remember that if you need to make changes to Project A later, then you'll need to repeat step 2 and restart VS.

Implement the code generator:

1. Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.14.0 to Project A.
2. Open your AssemblyInfo.cs file for Project A and change `[assembly: ComVisible(false)]` to `[assembly: ComVisible(true)]`
3. Create a new code generator class like below

   ```
   [ComVisible(true)]
   [Guid("C43E4E36-289C-40C8-9B87-7F79E2B57B0E")] // TODO: replace with your own random GUID
   public class MyResConverter : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.BaseCodeGenerator
   {
       public override string GetDefaultExtension()
       {
           // TODO: file extension of the resulting resource file
           return ".res.txt";
       }

       protected override byte[] GenerateCode(string inputFileName, string inputFileContent)
       {
           // TODO: your "compile" step that converts `src.txt` to `res.txt`
           return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputFileContent.ToUpper());
       }
   }
   ```

Register your code generator:

1. Compile Project A, and copy the resulting assemblies to some other folder. If you leave them in the build output directory, the files will be write-locked later, since Visual Studio will load them into memory after you register the custom tool with VS and restart VS.
2. Use regasm to register your Project A as a COM assembly, running from a command prompt as admin: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /codebase C:\Path\To\ProjectA.dll`
3. Create a new install.reg text file to configure VS to recognize your new Custom Tool from Project A, substituting TODOs as appropriate:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   ; TODO: Replace with your GUID
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\CLSID\{C43E4E36-289C-40C8-9B87-7F79E2B57B0E}]
   "InprocServer32"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\mscoree.dll"
   "ThreadingModel"="Both"
   "Class"="ProjectA.MyResConverter"
   ; TODO: Replace with your assembly
   "Assembly"="ProjectA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"
   ; TODO: Replace with your dll file
   "CodeBase"="file:///C:\\Path\\To\\ProjectA.dll"

   ; TODO: Replace with your tool name
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\Generators\{FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}\MyResConverter]
   ; TODO: Replace with your GUID
   "CLSID"="{C43E4E36-289C-40C8-9B87-7F79E2B57B0E}"
   "GeneratesDesignTimeSource"=dword:00000001
   ; TODO: Replace with your description
   @="My Custom Tool"
   ```

   - Note that this differs from [the tutorial](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/developing-custom-tool-aka-single-file-generators-for-visual-studio-2012/) mentioned above in that you're targeting the `14.0_Config` key since this is VS2015.
   - The `{FAE...` string is the GUID for C# code generators, and unrelated to any GUID you create for your custom code generator.
   - Note that this install.reg file *must be an ANSI-encoded* file, or else regedit.exe will reject with some "invalid registry file" error. If you create the install.reg file inside of VS as a Text File, it will be encoded as UTF8, so just create this in notepad.exe or whatever you like.
4. Run install.reg to update the registry
5. Restart Visual Studio

Use your Custom Tool:

1. Right click your `src.txt` in Project B, then Properties
2. Change the "Custom Tool" property to your tool's name that you specified in the install.reg, e.g. `MyResConverter`
3. Save your `src.txt` file to generate the initial transformed resource file (can just open `src.txt` and click File > Save to force the code generator to run). You should now see a `src.res.txt` underneath your `src.txt`. You can change the Properties on the generated file to embed it as a resource into your assembly, or whatever you want.

From now on, whenever you modify `src.txt`, VS will regenerate the resource file for you, which you can embed into your Project B.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer and a very good example. I'm going to accept the other answer only because this is a 1-off (only one file will be  foreseeably converted this way). But I will bookmark this for future reference if I need a solution for a bunch of files (like a actual compiler or something). I wish it was easier, without registering assemblies and so forth.